# How to change an icon in a html table TD element, according to another TD element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

this is my table in jquery:-

```
var tbody = $('#tblCsvRecords tbody'),
props = ["ShipmentType", "SCAC", "ShipmentControlNumber", "ProvinceofLoading", 
"ShipperName", "ConsigneeName"];
$.each(filedata, function (key, value) {
var tr = $('<tr>');
$.each(props, function (key, prop) {
$('<td>').html(value[prop]).appendTo(tr);
});
tbody.append(tr);
});
```

this is validation in jquery-

```
$.each(globalfiledata, function (key, value) {
if (value.ShipmentType != ("Regular Bill" || "Section 321")) {
           //show error sign and view error link as shown in image
}
});
```

html table -

```
<div id="tablediv" class="table-responsive">                                           
<table id="tblCsvRecords" class="table table3-1 bg-white no-margin-bottom">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Shipment Type </th>
<th>SCAC </th>
<th>Shipment Control Number </th>
<th>Port of Loading </th>
<th>Shipper Name </th>
<th>Consignee Name </th>
<th>Validated </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table id>
</div>
```

I want to display the error sign and the view error link for the popup in the validated column of the table. How can I do that?
 [image of validated column of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMw2N.png)

I want to display error message in the modal -"enter valid shipment type" if Iserror is true how should i do that?  below is the
working updated code-

Comment: What is `globalfiledata` ?

Comment: it is an array.

Comment: So, it doesn't relate to the `td` or DOM itself?  It's just an array of values?  How does it get populated?  There needs to be some way to relate `globalfiledata` to the DOM if you want to modify the content of a `td`.  If we can see how it gets populated with values, it's possible that will help relate it to the DOM structure.  Can you update your question with that segment of code?

Comment: globalfiledata-

ConsigneeName: "Bread ghj"
ProvinceofLoading: "ON"
QuantityUnit: "Case"
SCAC: "ABCF"
ShipmentControlNumber: "20185678781"
ShipmentType: "Regular"
ShipperAddress: "3788 Street"
ShipperCity: "Alberta"
ShipperCountry: "CA"
ShipperEmail: ""
ShipperName: "ZZ"
Weight: "10000"
WeightUnit: "Kilograms"

these values are coming from globalfile data. and these below values i am using only to  insert data in the table ShipmentType", "SCAC", "ShipmentControlNumber", "ProvinceofLoading", "ShipperName", "ConsigneeName

Comment: So, you're not going to be able to update a `td` based on `globalfiledata`.  There is no relation to the DOM.  Can you do your validation somewhere else, like where you iterate over `filedata` to create the table / rows ?

Comment: filedata and globalfiledata are the same. I wanted to use filedata in some function so i declared it globally and name it as globalfiledata.

Comment: Can you please tell how to append icon and view error part into the validated column of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you don't need to iterate over `globalfiledata` for the validation.  You can do the validation when you're building the table, here:

```
$.each(filedata, function (key, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    var isError = false; //set isError false at the beginning of every row iteration
    $.each(props, function (key, prop) {
         //do your validation here
         if(prop === "ShipmentType" && value !== ("Regular Bill" || "Section 321")) {
            isError = true;
        }
        $('<td>').text(value).appendTo(tr); //fixed this line in your code to match your data structure, and to actually write the value to the td text because it's not html
    });
    //then, the last column is for Validation, so add your validation td here:
    var td = $('<td>');
    if(isError) {
        //insert your error image and link here, which will look something like:
        td.text('View Error');
        var link = $('<a>').attr('href','//href value goes here');
        $('<img>').attr('src','///img src goes here').wrap(link).appendTo(td);
    }
    td.appendTo(tr);
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

Comment: Its is looping for every value of prop in this and going to the loop
 $.each(props, function (key, prop) {

This part is not working - 
prop === "ShipmentType"

Comment: @harleenkaur : isn't "ShipmentType" a valid value for prop?  And it represents the first column, which is what you want to inspect for validation, right?

Comment: @harleenkaur : I found a typo in my answer and fixed it.  I also changed the comparison to look at `value` instead of `value[prop]` because 'value[prop]` does not match your data structure.  If this still isn't working, please EDIT your question and add in a valid data sample.

Comment: td.text('View Error'); View Errors is not clickable, its is just displaying as a text.. what should I write instead of var link = $('<a>').attr('href','//href value goes here');?

Comment: I have updated the working code,I want to display error message in the modal -"enter valid shipment type" if Iserror is true how should i do that? on click of View errors , modal will be displayed.

Comment: @harleenkaur - please don't make your question a moving target.  If I answered your original question, mark this as the answer and open another question to ask your new question.

Comment: i have created the new question. thanks for your kind help.